# How to get Gutenberg Reusable Block content when retrieving post content?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, gutenberg-reusable-block

I’ve created a WordPress plugin that converts post content to speech. It’s not a surprise that on of the basic requirements for such plugin is reliable retrieving post content. I’m using `get_post_field('post_content')` and everything seems to work fine except one thing: if there’s **Reusable Block** within posts content – the function doesn’t return it. It gives me all the content except **Reusable Block**.

Is there some workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll want to apply the `the_content` filter to get the reusable blocks' content.

```
apply_filters('the_content', get_post_field('post_content'));
```

There may be a more efficient function for pulling the content (`get_the_content` maybe?), but regardless this should convert the reusable blocks to html.